# AutoHotKey remap win key

Tags: autohotkey

I want to make windows keyboard shortcuts like mac.

I'm using a real mac keyboard (the keys in the left bottom corner are `Ctrl`, `Alt`, `Win`)

So I need:

1. Set some special hotkey with `Win` + `...` (e.g. `Win` `Q` => `Alt` `F4`, code is `#Q::Send !{F4}`)
2. Map other `Win` + `...` => `Ctrl` + `...` (e.g. `Win` `A` => `Ctrl` `A` and `Win` `S` => `Ctrl` `S`)
3. Keep origin behavior if `Win` key has pressed alone (open start menu)

Then I ran into problems with the step 2 and 3.
For step 2, If I map `LWin::LCtrl`, the hotkeys in step 1 won't work anymore.
For step 3, I found a solution that measure how long was the `Win` key pressed. But I want a more precise way like checking if any other key was pressed between the `Win` key down and up. I have no idea to implement it.

After this, I have a more special requirement.

4. Map `Ctrl` + `Win` + ... => `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `...`, that is to say map `Win` to `Alt` only if `Ctrl` has been pressed. (e.g. `Ctrl` `Win` `A` => `Ctrl` `Alt` `A`).

Comment: I see some contradiction, why would you map `LWin::LCtrl` if you want to "keep origin behavior if Win key has pressed alone (open start menu)"

Comment: I'd assume for `Win+` Shortcuts to be treated as `Ctrl+` shortcuts @0x464e

Comment: @0x464e Just like @Spyre said. I said `LWin::LCtrl` is only for a hypothesis. My problems is exactly how to archive the point 1, 3 and 4 base `LWin::LCtrl`.

Comment: I'm sorry for my pool English. You can edit the question to help me describe it more clearly.